# Why wont my Java code pick up the value of the JText field?

Tags: java, swing, null, jtextfield

Im trying to get a value from a text field (entered by the users) to use for processing. But no matter what I do it will not get the value that was entered it seem to remain empty. Could some one please tell me why it will not get the value from the Text field.

this is the method which initialy created the text field which was named writeStrings

```
public void chooseEmpToAdd()
{
     JTextArea EmpDetails = new JTextArea(5,20);
     JTextField writeStrings  = new JTextField(20); 
     JLabel enterIDno = new JLabel("Please enter The Employye ID number that you wish to assign to a department: ");  

     JButton  submit  = new JButton  (" Submit") ;
       ButtonListenerEmp Listener2 = new ButtonListenerEmp(); 
      submit.addActionListener(Listener2);
     JFrame frameAllEmps = new JFrame();
      frameAllEmps.setSize( 150, 140 );
     frameAllEmps.pack();
     frameAllEmps.setVisible(true); 

     //layout
     frameAllEmps.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      frameAllEmps.add(enterIDno);

    int x = 0;
    System.out.println("ALL Emps from the tree map");
    for(int key:employeeMap.keySet())
    {

        Employee dEmp = employeeMap.get(key);
        System.out.println("Employe no :" +x+": "+dEmp);
        EmpDetails.setText(EmpDetails.getText()+" "+dEmp);
        frameAllEmps.add(EmpDetails);   
         x++;
    }

    frameAllEmps.add(new JScrollPane(EmpDetails));
    frameAllEmps.add(writeStrings);
    frameAllEmps.add(submit);
    frameAllEmps.pack();

}
```

And this is the action listener which should take the value from the Text box and print it to the console, but it does not work.

```
 private class ButtonListenerEmp implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e )
        {
            String ID ; 
            int dID;


               ID = writeStrings.getText();
                System.out.println("start of try b4 changes: "+ID);     
               }
           }
```

Comment: The problem could easily be in code not shown.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listener implementation shouldn't have access to the local variable `writeStrings`, I'm not even sure how that would compile--is the code you posted accurate?

Oh, you probably have both a local variable `writeStrings`, *and* an instance variable `writeStrings`, although it's hard to say since you didn't post the rest of the code. Try not declaring `writeStrings` in the `chooseEmpToAdd` method; use the class variable instead.

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for being in touch. Yes the code compiles okay. Their would be far to much code if I put the whole lot up.

What is a class variable is that when the textField is declared wrire at the beggining of the class

Comment: @Binyomin Yes, although I meant instance variable.

Comment: @Binyomin Cool :) Remember to accept answers (when they're right, anyway) so future visitors with similar problems can be helped!

Answer (score 2):

Because you're declaring the text field as a local variable of `chooseEmpToAdd` method, so it is not being seen by `ButtonListenerEmp` class. To solve this problem, declare the text field as a class field and make it public or pass the text of the text field as an argument of `ButtonListenerEmp` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The variable ID might not have been initialized (i.e. `String ID = "";`)

Also there is a compile error at the line `writeStrings.getText()` because the variable `writeStrings` doesn't exist outside of the `chooseEmpToAdd()` method. Try declaring `JTextField writeStrings = new JTextField(20);` before the method instead.

Comment: ID is immediately assigned, and it's not used before it's assigned--not all IDE warnings are useful. Also, OP states the value of the text field is always empty, so there's clearly not a compilation error, which is how we could diagnose that there's an instance variable being shadowed by the method's local declaration.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to my mind from the code presented is that you create the new `JTextField` and store it in a **local** variable called `writeStrings` maybe that is not the same you try to read from lateron.